# Display message in a toastr after controller method finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, toastr

i have controller method that upload image file, **not** using jQuery AJAX, from `<input>` type "file", the method returns:

```
Return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery)
```

Because i want to stay in the same view after the submit click.

I want to show after the success image upload, `toastr.success`.

How i can do it?

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page then use ajax. Alternatively if you redirecting back to the same page or another page), then you need to pass the message to it.

Comment: How i pass the message?

Comment: Numerous ways - e.g. from the POST method to the GET method via `TempData` and then to the view using `ViewData` if your redirecting. This is way to broad.

Answer (score 5):

In your http post action method, after successful upload, set an entry to TempData dictionary and read it in the next view which is loaded by the Redirect method and display the toastr message.

```
TempData["Msg"] = "Uploaded successfully";
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
```

in your view

```
<script>
  $(function(){
     var msg = "@(TempData["Msg"] as string)";
     if (msg !== "") {
         toastr.success(msg);
     }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there another possible way besides TempData? I'm running into an issue with configuring session

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.

1. Create a Toastr model that includes Message, Title, Type, SessionID and Date.

   ```
   public class Toastr
   {
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Message { get; set; }
       public ToastrType Type { get; set; }
       public string SessionId { get; set; }
       public DateTime Date { get; set; }

       public Toastr(string message, string title = "Information" , ToastrType type = ToastrType.Info)
       {
           this.Message = message;
           this.Title = title;
           this.Type = type;
           this.Date = DateTime.Now;
       }
   }

   public enum ToastrType
   {
       Info = 0,
       Success = 1,
       Warning = 2,
       Error = 3
   }
   ```
2. Create a Service or Manager where you define your basic functions (add, remove toasts)

   ```
   private static List<Toastr> _toasts = new List<Toastr>();

   private static string GetSession()
   {
       return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
   }
   public static void AddToUserQueue(Toastr toastr)
   {
       toastr.SessionId = GetSession();
       _toasts.Add(toastr);
   }
   public static void AddToUserQueue(string message, string title, ToastrType type)
   {

       var toast = new Toastr(message, title, type);
       toast.SessionId = GetSession();
       AddToUserQueue(toast);
   }
   public static bool HasQueue()
   {
       return _toasts.Any(t => t.SessionId == GetSession());
   }
   public static void RemoveUserQueue()
   {
       _toasts.RemoveAll(t => t.SessionId == GetSession());
   }
   public static void ClearAll()
   {
       _toasts.Clear();
   }
   public static List<Toastr> GetUserQueue()
   {
       if (HasQueue())               
           return _toasts.Where(t => t.SessionId == GetSession())
                       .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date)
                       .ToList();
       return null;
   }
   public static List<Toastr> GetAndRemoveUserQueue()
   {
       var list = GetUserQueue();
       RemoveUserQueue();

       return list;
   }
   ```
3. In your layout / page make use of the functions by creating some helpers.

   ```
   @helper ProcessToasts()
   {
       List<Toastr> toasts = ToastrManager.GetAndRemoveUserQueue();
       if (toasts != null && toasts.Count > 0)
       {
           foreach (var item in toasts)
           {
               @ShowToastr(item);
           }
       }
   }
   @helper ShowToastr(Toastr item)
   {
       switch (item.Type)
       {
           case ToastrType.Info:
               @ToastrInfo(item.Message, item.Title)
               break;
           case ToastrType.Success:
               @ToastrSuccess(item.Message, item.Title)
               break;
           case ToastrType.Warning:
               @ToastrWarning(item.Message, item.Title)
               break;
           case ToastrType.Error:
               @ToastrError(item.Message, item.Title);
               break;
       }
   }

   @helper ToastrInfo(string message, string title)
   {
       <script>
            toastr.info("@message","@title")
       </script>
   }
   @helper ToastrSuccess(string message, string title)
   {
       <script>
            toastr.success("@message","@title")
       </script>
   }
   @helper ToastrWarning(string message, string title)
   {
       <script>
            toastr.warning("@message","@title")
       </script>
   }
   @helper ToastrError(string message, string title)
   {
       <script>
            toastr.error("@message","@title")
       </script>
   }
   ```
4. Since the helpers are below closing HTML tag, you need just to add the `@ProcessToasts()` right before the body closing tag.